# When should I combine two foreign keys as a single foreign key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

My teach said I should combine two foreign keys into a single primary key. But my thought process is that that would allow for only one combination of each foreign key.

Imagine I have a Product, Purchase, PurchaseDetail.

In PurchaseDetail I have two foreign keys, one for product and one for purchase. My teacher said that I should combine these two foreign keys into a single one. But can't a product be in many different purchases? And many purchases have many products?

I'm confused.

Thanks!

Edit: This is the SQL my teacher saw and then gave feedback upon. Thanks for the guidance guys. (I changed the essential to English)

```
create table Purchase
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    IDCliente int foreign key references Cliente(ID),
    IDEmpleado int foreign key references Empleado(ID),
    Fecha datetime not null,
    Hora datetime not null,
    Amount float not null,
)

create table PurchaseDetail
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    IDPurchase int foreign key references Purchase(ID),
    IDProductOffering int foreign key references ProductOffering(ID),
    Quantity int not null
)

create table Product
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    IDProveedor int foreign key references Proveedor(ID),
    Nombre nvarchar(256) not null,
    IDSubcategoria int foreign key references Subcategoria(ID),
    IDMarca int foreign key references Marca(ID),
    Fotografia nvarchar(1024) not null
)

create table ProductOffering
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    IDProduct int foreign key references Product(ID),
    Price float not null,
    OfferDate datetime not null,
)
```

Maybe I'm confused about good database schema design. Thanks again!

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the scenario you mentioned?  Any example or reason?

Comment: Either you misunderstood your teacher, or he's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine he's suggesting:

- Product - one primary key (product id), which implies a unique product id
- Purchase - one primary key (purchase id), which implies a unique purchase id
- PurchaseDetail - two foreign keys (product id),(purchase id), plus one unique constraint on (product id + purchase id)

Plus some people argue that all tables should have their own primary key that doesn't depend on anything else (purchase detail id). Some DBMS make this mandatory.

This means that you can't have two rows in PurchaseDetail that have the same product and purchase. That makes sense, assuming there is also a quantity column on PurchaseDetail, so that one purchase can have more than one of each product.

Note that there is a difference between a *unique constraint* and a *foreign key*. A foreign key merely says that there should be an item with that id in the parent table - it will let you create as many references to that item as you want in the child table. You need to specify that the column or combination of columns are unique if you want to avoid duplicates. A primary key on the other hand implies a unique constraint.

Exact syntax for defining all of this varies by language, but those are the principles.

Comment: I'm not refering to a particular language/implementation, rather the set theoretic...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Not neccesarily, but in this case they are definitely two separate foreign keys. The are not used combined to reference any table.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, although it can reference two columns in the same table (at least in postgres). I will correct.

Comment: @Guffa. I think you are incorrect. Can you please provide a link to an RBDMS that allows a FK to be made up of columns from different tables...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: How did you get from a FK referencing more than one table to a FK made up of columns from different tables?

Comment: In relational database theory, a "foreign key" refers to a set of attributes of a relation, which might include references to any number of other relations (or relation variables). In SQL a FOREIGN KEY is the name of a *constraint* which can only reference base tables and permits references to only one table. I guess this is another example of where SQL has caused confusion by borrowing a term from the relational database model and using it with a different meaning.

Comment: Like this? CREATE TABLE tbl (x INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES tbl1 (x), FOREIGN KEY (x) REFERENCES tbl2 (x), ...);

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the single key, but they could be a compound key (which I tend to dislike). They can be two different fields each restricted to the ID in the corresponding tables.

Not sure why the same product iD would need to be listed more than once for a single purchase? Isn't that why you indicate quantity?  Maybe the need to do a separate line item for a purchase and a discount?

Answer (score 0):

I believe thelem has answered correctly. But there is another option. You could add a new primary key column to the details table, so it looks like this:

```
detail_id   int (PK)
product_id  int (FK)
purchsae_id int (FK)
```

This is not really necessary, but it could be useful if you need to ever need to reference the details table as a foreign key - having a single primary key field makes for smaller indexes and foreign key reference (and they are a little easier to type).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps he is suggesting a many-to-many table where it's Primary Key is comprised of the Foreign Keys to the mapped tables:

```
PurchaseDetail:

ProductId          int (FK) 
PurchaseId         int (FK) 
PK(ProductId, PurchaseId)
```

This can also be modelled as

```
PurchaseDetail:

PurchaseDetailId   int (PK, Identity)
ProductId          int (FK) 
PurchaseId         int (FK)
```

The second form is useful if you want to refer to Purchase details elsewhere in your model, and also in some RDBMS's it is beneficial to have a PK on a montonically increasing integer.

Comment: That's what I did, and he gave the feedback (the basis of this question). Please see my edit. :P I did what you're suggesting, but he seemed to dislike it.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what data you need to represent.

If you use the two foreign keys as the primary key for the purchase detail, a product may only occur once in each purchase. A purchase may however still contain many products, and a product may still occur in many purchases.

If the purchase detail contains more information, you may need to be able to use a product more than once in a purchase. For example if the purchase detail contains size and color, and you want to by a red T-shirt size XL and a blue T-shirt size S.